# Unable to see convert to testng in run configuration in eclipse unless I download its plugin

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I already have testng dependency in my pom.xml and it is detecting my tests with @Test annotation.
Issue is, it is not present in my run configurations like following:
[Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNp1T.png)

If I manually install testng plugin, then it appears but I was thinking, the plugins we install from marketplace, they are only installed on local machine. They will not be pushed to git.
What solutions could be done?
I tried again downloading testng dependencies, configuring java buildpath. No luck. Only thing which worked for me was manually downloading testng plugin from marketplace

Comment: Why do you think the plugin is pushed to repository? What exactly is committed?

Comment: It is not. I am just asking from best practice point of view.

Comment: But plugin only adds the framework support to eclipse. You don't need any plugin to run the tests directly from maven. Plugin only adds some fancy features to your IDE, but it's not required. In repository you only keep the code. The IDE is for user, if someone want to use eclipse with testng plugin - that's his/her choice. But others may want to use intellij, or vs code, or notepad or even vim to develop the code, so there is no need to commit the plugin to the repository.